# how to array_push a string into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, push, array-push

Here is the problem:

```
  $arr = array(array());

  $arr[0]['a'] = 'for 0.a';
  $arr[0]['b'] = 'for 0.b';
  $arr[1]['a'] = 'for 1.a';
  $arr[1]['b'] = 'for 1.b';

  array_push($arr,'for 2.a');
  array_push($arr,'for 2.b');

  print_r($arr);
```

String "for 2.a" should be in `$arr[2]['a']`. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_push($arr,array('a'=>'for 2.a','b'=>'for 2.b'));`

or

```
$arr[2]['a'] = 'for 2.a';
$arr[2]['b'] = 'for 2.b';
```